# Localizing an already developed application using google translater

Tags: iphone

"How to localize a project i.e., already developed in some language by using Google translater". please tell me i have n't any idea on that.

Answer (score 1):

Please, don't use Google translator for localizing your app! Google translator is a mechanic translator, not a human. The results are not very good. (Try to read an instruction book which was translated from Chinese to English ;) )

If your app is popular or has some fans, ask the community for some nativ speaker. Or if you have an payed app, you could go to some kind of a translator-agency.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Language API. There is a lot of documentation and help [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/)